# How to fix cannot load such file -- Nokogiri (LoadError) in c9.io?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, cloud9-ide

I'm using Cloud9 IO for Ruby.
I ran bundle install.
Even installed the gems.
But I'm still getting this error.

> scarletmclearn:~/workspace/nokogiri_tutorial (master) $ ruby
>   web_scraper.rb
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- Nokogiri (LoadError)
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'
>           from web_scraper.rb:1:in `'

Do check out my Repository : https://github.com/ScarletMcLearn/ruby_ws_1/tree/master/workspace

a beginner here, so simple instructions on which file or what to change will help.

Thanks for the read!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". We shouldn't have to look through your code repository to find the problem. Instead, you need to supply the smallest example of your code that demonstrates the problem you're having _in the question itself_. From a quick glance at your code you have major issues. I'd suggest backing away from Rails temporarily and concentrate on some Ruby tutorials. Once you have a good understanding of Ruby then look at Rails again.

Comment: Notice that you didn't put Nokogiri in your bundle. That's only one of many problems in your code.

Answer (score 3):

from your command prompt install nokogiri by running

```
gem install nokogiri
```